# PyQt: How to get a signal from QCombobox which is a QTableWidgetItem

Tags: pyqt, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I have a QTableWidget table where the first columns of each row are QComboBoxex, which in turn are QTableWidgetItems of the table, the rest are normal text input cells.

Could you please tell me how to get "currentIndexChanged(int)" signals from any of the QComboboxes which will tell me the row numbers the comboboxex fired them from?

The following doesn't work:

```
def insert_row_cb(self, table, cb_col):
    rows = table.rowCount()
    table.insertRow(rows)
    self.set_row_items_cb(table, cb_col)
    self.resize_rows(table)
    return table

def set_row_items_cb(self, table, cb_col):
    cb = QtGui.QComboBox()
    signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper()

    rows = table.rowCount()
    cols = table.columnCount()
    for col in range(cols):
        if col == cb_col:
            table.setCellWidget(rows - 1, cb_col, cb)
            signalMapper.setMapping(cb, table.item(0, 0))
            cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(signalMapper.map)
            signalMapper.mapped.connect(self.cb_index_changed)
        else:
            table.setItem(rows - 1, col, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(''))
    return table

def cb_index_changed(self, index):
    print(index)
```

Thank you.

*** EDIT - I GOT IT! ***

My DataTable class:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class DataTable(QtCore.QObject):
cb_index_changed_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QWidget)
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

    self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper()
    self.signalMapper.mapped[QtGui.QWidget].connect(self.on_signalMapper_mapped)

def insert_row_cb(self, table, cb_col):
    rows = table.rowCount()
    table.insertRow(rows)
    self.set_row_items_cb(table, cb_col)
    self.resize_rows(table)
    return table

def set_row_items_cb(self, table, cb_col):
    cb = QtGui.QComboBox()
    cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.signalMapper.map)

    rows = table.rowCount()
    cols = table.columnCount()
    for col in range(cols):
        if col == cb_col:
            table.setCellWidget(rows - 1, cb_col, cb)
            cb.row = rows - 1
            cb.column = cb_col
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(cb, cb)
        else:
            table.setItem(rows - 1, col, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(''))
    return table

def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, cb):
    self.cb_index_changed_signal.emit(cb)
```

Here in another class I create a table:

```
from scripts.data_table import DataTable

self.data_table = DataTable(self)
self.consumption_table = self.data_table.insert_row_cb(self.consumption_table, 0)
self.data_table.cb_index_changed_signal.connect(self.cb_index_changed_signal)

def cb_index_changed_signal(self, cb):
    print ("row: "+str(cb.row)+" column: "+str(cb.column)+" text: "+cb.currentText())
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

#---------
# IMPORT
#---------
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

#---------
# MAIN
#---------
class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        numberRows    = 3
        numberColumns = 3

        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(numberRows)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(numberColumns)

        self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)
        self.signalMapper.mapped[QtGui.QWidget].connect(self.on_signalMapper_mapped)

        for rowNumber in range(numberRows):
            for columnNumber in range(numberColumns):    
                comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
                comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
                comboBox.addItems([
                    "{0}-{1}-{2}".format(rowNumber, columnNumber, itemNumber)
                    for itemNumber in range(3)
                ])
                comboBox.row = rowNumber
                comboBox.column = columnNumber

                self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(rowNumber, columnNumber, comboBox)

                self.signalMapper.setMapping(comboBox, comboBox)

        self.layoutVertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QWidget)
    def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, comboBox):
        print "row: {0} column: {1} text: {2}".format(
            comboBox.row,
            comboBox.column,
            comboBox.currentText()
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.resize(333, 111)
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked! However, it only works in its own class, in my case I have a class DataTable with all properties necessary to create a table, insert/delete rows etc. So, I can print all the info about the combobox. But how do I return that info to another class which calls the DataTable properties? What signals/slots do I connect there? See code above. Thank you.

Comment: @linuxoid did you solve the problem? I have another class as well and the problems are the same as yours.

Comment: I haven't touched Python for years... ))) Please have a look there: https://sourceforge.net/projects/libreeng/